# How do I set up VSCode to use Kotlin and Java?

Tags: java, linux, kotlin, visual-studio-code

I am just starting to learn how to code with Kotlin and for that, I am trying to configure VSCode (Version 1.61) as it is my main IDE.

I am using a pc with the following characteristics:

- Static hostname: pop-os
- Operating System: Pop!_OS 21.04
- Kernel: Linux 5.13.0-7614-generic
- Architecture: x86-64

I have verified that I have java, kotlin and kotlic installed:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2, mixed mode, sharing)
$ kotlin -version
Kotlin version 1.5.31-release-548 (JRE 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2)
$ kotlinc -version
info: kotlinc-jvm 1.5.31 (JRE 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2)
```

In Vscode I have installed the following extensions:

- Kotlin Language by mathiasfrohlich
- Code Runner by Jun Han
- Extension Pack for Java by Microsoft
- Debugger for Java by Microsoft
- Language Support for Java by Red Hat

After doing all this I created a folder `~/Learning/Kotlin/HelloWorld/` with a simple kotlin file `"helloworld.kt"` containing the following code:

```
fun fun main(args: Array<String>) {
println("Hello Kotlin")
}
```

When trying to run the code, I received an error about not finding the kotlinc command, so I added the following to the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export KOTLIN_HOME=/home/usr/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current
export PATH=$PATH:$KOTLIN_HOME/bin
```

However, now I am getting the following error:

```
[Running] cd "/home/mantress31/Documents/Manuel/Aprendizaje/Kotlin/Hello World/" && kotlinc helloworld.kt -include-runtime -d helloworld.jar && java -jar helloworld.jar
/home/usr/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/bin/kotlinc: line 98: java: command not found
```

Could someone tell me if I have done something wrong while configuring all this? And/Or What else should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Why not using Intellij Idea https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ the community version is free and is made by the same people that made Kotlin.

Comment: I agree. Main reason to try to use VSCode would be to maybe save some time learning a new IDE, but you’ll spend far more time trying to get everything running correctly, and figuring out quirks on your own. Plus, you’ll have a limited feature set when it comes to configuring the project through the UI, and shortcuts for boilerplate and refactoring.

Comment: I was thinking VSCode because I have been using it to learn other languages so I am somewhat used to it. In any case, I just installed IntelliJ Community, but it asks me to select a JDK, which I cannot find anywhere even though as you can see above, it seems like I already have installed the Openjdk. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the best way of solving the problem, but I managed to make it work by doing the following:

First, I installed Oracle's JDK following the instructions in this video: [Installing Oracle JDK on Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogWKP9Lm-Qo).

After that, I went to the `.bashrc` file (In my pc it is located on the home folder), and added the following: `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`. After doing this, I reset the file with the `source ~/.bashrc`.

The error in VSCode was fixed after doing this. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.